# Error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in (envió de mail)

Tags: php, mysql, email

Realizo un modulo en el cual los usuarios registran los incidentes que se les presenta en su área de trabajo este a su vez lo inserta en mi BD y lo envía por correo, hasta aquí todo esta bien.

El problema que tengo es que mi BD esta diseñada para que mi tabla central ticket consulte los ID de otras tablas foráneas y los inserte en lugar de las cadenas que a largo plazo alimentan las BD, por tal motivo al realizar el envío de correo me envía los ID y lo que necesito es que consulte que cadena le pertenece a ese ID y sea la cadena que llegue al correo.

Tengo el problema en esta parte del código cuando trato de guardar los valores resultantes en $datos

**Error:**`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in`

es en esta parte del código

```
$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Área:</strong> " . $datos->area_id; 
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";
```

Código php (completo)

```
<?php
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
$query= "SELECT 
t.id, t.title, are.name are_desc, 
fin.name fin_desc, cat.name cat_desc, 
sub.name sub_desc, pri.name pri_desc 
FROM ticket t 
INNER JOIN area are ON are.id = t.area_id 
INNER JOIN final fin ON fin.id = t.final_id 
INNER JOIN category cat ON cat.id = t.category_id 
INNER JOIN sub_categoria sub ON sub.id = t.subcategoria_id 
INNER JOIN priority pri ON pri.id = t.priority_id 
WHERE fin.id = t.final_id 
order by t.id DESC LIMIT 1
"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$datos = datos[0];

$to = 'soporteit@gmail.com';

$cabeceras = 'From: ' . " " . $final_id . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Bcc: desarrollos.web95@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";

$msjCorreo = "<img src='C:/xampp/htdocs/tickets.usuarios/images/logo.jpg'>
<center><h3><strong>Sistema de Registro de Incidencias</strong></h3></center>
<center>Para nosotros es un placer asistirle el día de hoy, a continuación le " .
"brindamos la información correspondiente a su incidente. En un momento nuestro " .
"ingeniero de soporte en turno acudirá a su lugar de trabajo</center><br/><br/><br/>" .
"<strong>Solicitud de Atención:</strong>" . $title;

$msjCorreo .= "<br /> <br />";
$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Área:</strong> " . $datos->area_id; 
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Usuario Final:</strong> " . $datos->final_id;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";


$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Categoría: </strong>" . $datos->category_id;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Sub Categoria: </strong>" . $datos->subcategoria_id;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Prioridad: </strong>" . $datos->priority_id;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br /><br />";


$msjCorreo .= "

Gracias<br />
Departamento de Sistemas<br />

";
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

if (mail($to, "Nueva Solicitud de Atención", $msjCorreo, $cabeceras)) {

} else {
  echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('fallado');
  </script>";
}
```

Comment: @Aprendiz, gracias por responder si coloco esta linea `$res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` con el código original me arroja estos errores `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets.usuarios\action\addticket.php on line 185

Notice: Undefined variable: datos in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets.usuarios\action\addticket.php on line 189`

Comment: Y si hago lo que mencionabas primero no me arrojaba ningún error solo que en el correo que se recibía no me trae las cadenas correctas solo me muestra una letra b

Comment: me arroja un error nuevo  `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$area_id in`

Comment: @Aprendiz agradecere mucho tu retroalimentación

Comment: puede ser que `area_id` no está en el select

Comment: @aloMalbarez es el resultante del inner join, ya que en mi tabla se insertan los ID pero necesito que haga esa consulta y dependiendo de cual es la cadena correspondiente a ese ID, en mi tabla foranea sea esa la que me envie por correo.

Comment: en el select no se ve ningún `area_id`, por mas que lo uses de enlace para el join si no está en el select no sale al final ( mismo vale para el resto de los `*_id` )

Comment: el select así como está te va a traer: id, title, are_desc, fin_desc, cat_desc, sub_desc y pri_desc . id va a ser el id de ticket

Comment: @aloMalbarez la construcción de mi consulta esta así `are.name are_desc` are es un identificador para mi tabla foranea y name asi se llama el campo donde esta la cadena `INNER JOIN area are ON are.id = t.area_id` en el inner consulta en la tabla foranea y en la tabla principal de echo ejecuto mi inner en mi consola y es correcta

Comment: Por supuesto @alo Malbarez, que ciego estuve a ese detalle; si la columna no se enuncia en el select no la va a recuperar

Comment: La consulta seguramente sea correcta, no hay dudas, pero el select no trae ningún campo terminado en `_id`, esos campos sólo existen en el servidor de base de datos para hacer el join. Lo que enumera el select es lo que recibe php.

Comment: @aloMalbarez estimado seras muy amable de ponerme un ejemplo de como quedaría mi select ya que me estoy confundiendo, ya llevo varios días tratando de que funcione este modulo y no lo consigo :(

Comment: @aloMalbarez corregui asi mi select `Select t.id, t.title, area_id, final_id, category_id, subcategoria_id, priority_id 
FROM ticket t 
INNER JOIN area are ON are.id = t.area_id 
INNER JOIN final fin ON fin.id = t.final_id 
INNER JOIN category cat ON cat.id = t.category_id 
INNER JOIN sub_categoria sub ON sub.id = t.subcategoria_id 
INNER JOIN priority pri ON pri.id = t.priority_id 
WHERE fin.id = t.final_id 
order by t.id DESC LIMIT 1` pero me devuelve este error `Notice: Use of undefined constant datos - assumed 'datos' in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un error en tu código en $dato = dato[0], ese dato debe obtenerlo del resultado de la consulta, además no los estas tratando como objetos, esto debería funcionar siempre que tu query tenga los datos que utilizas.

```
<?php
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
$query= "SELECT 
t.id, t.title, are.name are_desc, 
fin.name fin_desc, cat.name cat_desc, 
sub.name sub_desc, pri.name pri_desc 
FROM ticket t 
INNER JOIN area are ON are.id = t.area_id 
INNER JOIN final fin ON fin.id = t.final_id 
INNER JOIN category cat ON cat.id = t.category_id 
INNER JOIN sub_categoria sub ON sub.id = t.subcategoria_id 
INNER JOIN priority pri ON pri.id = t.priority_id 
WHERE fin.id = t.final_id 
order by t.id DESC LIMIT 1
"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$datos = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

$to = 'soporteit@gmail.com';

$cabeceras = 'From: ' . " " . $final_id . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Bcc: desarrollos.web95@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";

$msjCorreo = "<img src='C:/xampp/htdocs/tickets.usuarios/images/logo.jpg'>
<center><h3><strong>Sistema de Registro de Incidencias</strong></h3></center>
<center>Para nosotros es un placer asistirle el día de hoy, a continuación le " .
"brindamos la información correspondiente a su incidente. En un momento nuestro " .
"ingeniero de soporte en turno acudirá a su lugar de trabajo</center><br/><br/><br/>" .
"<strong>Solicitud de Atención:</strong>" . $title;

$msjCorreo .= "<br /> <br />";
$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Área:</strong> " . $datos->area_desc; 
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Usuario Final:</strong> " . $datos->fin_desc;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";


$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Categoría: </strong>" . $datos->cat_desc;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Sub Categoria: </strong>" . $datos->sub_desc;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Prioridad: </strong>" . $datos->pri_desc;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br /><br />";


$msjCorreo .= "

Gracias<br />
Departamento de Sistemas<br />

";
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

if (mail($to, "Nueva Solicitud de Atención", $msjCorreo, $cabeceras)) {

} else {
  echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('fallado');
  </script>";
}
```

Comment: gracias por responder, ya lo habia intentado de esta forma que me mencionas pero me arroja este error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$area_id in`

Comment: Deja el código hasta el $datos e imprime lo que te devuelve con **print_r($datos);**, te debería aparecer area_id, si no te aparece hay un problema con tu query.

Comment: ya encontre mi error añadi la linea que me mencionas pero  donde recupera el valor coloque un alias  que lo declare en mi consulta 
`$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Área:</strong> " . $datos->are_desc; 
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";` corrijo el código ya correcto como lo tengo

Comment: @Carlos me alegra poder ayudado! :D